# Paste formatting loses formatting in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting, spreadsheet, excel-2019

I have two excel sheets (excel 2019)

source_file.xlsx. You can find my source sheet [here](https://github.com/Sydney-Informatics-Hub/copy_xlsx_styles/issues/7)

dest_file.xlsx

Am trying to split the data from source_file.xlsx and save it as multiple dest_files such as
dest_file1.xlsx, dest_file2.xlsx, dest_file3.xlsx

Later, I manually try to paste the formatting from `source_file.xlsx` to each of `dest_files`

My source file looks like below

[image]

So, I did the below in source_file.xlsx

CTRL+A --> CTRL+C

Navigated to dest_file1.xlsx and did the below

CTRL+V and choose the below

[image]

**But the problem is, this doesn't copy the colors from source_file.xlsx and paste it in dest_file1.xlsx
Can I seek your help to understand what could be the problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't look like *true* formatting. Rather, it looks like an Excel table which has formatting of it's own but is governed by table rules instead of something like color this one cell green. In your multiple dest_files, click any cell and then Home > Format as Table.

Comment: Do you know how can I find the table formatting style used in my sheet? Is there ajy menu option in excel that lets us know? So, I can recreate that?